# Two different login screens on Ubuntu 18.10!

Tags: login-screen, gdm, bug-reporting

So i installed Ubuntu 18.10 fresh install and i did have the normal new login screen of ubuntu gdm3. Ive been downloading gnome themes and i noticed after i did everything(idk if its from installing new themes) when locking the computer i still get the normal lock screen 
And when i slide it up i get the stamdart login screen:

1. Lock screen
   [image]
2. Login screen
   [image]

But now it gets weird when i click on "Log in as another user" i get a new different type of log in screen, which comes when booting into ubuntu after the logo loading screen too(on this login screen the tap-to-click also doesnt work!):

3. 2nd login screen
   [image]

EDIT:
Im sorry i forgot to add a question 
- What is this(is this normal?) and how to set it back to default?

Added theme: 
Named "flat remix"
[image]

I would be happy for your help
Thanks
Best Regards!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90188/discussion-on-question-by-amin-dieter-hatib-two-different-login-screens-on-ubunt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the package `flat-remix-gnome` is installed..
it automatically updates the alternatives for `gdm3.css`

```
$ sudo apt install flat-remix-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfcitx-config4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flat-remix-gnome
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,754 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 flat-remix-gnome amd64 3.30.13-1 [1,754 kB]
Fetched 1,754 kB in 33s (53.8 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package flat-remix-gnome.
(Reading database ... 204723 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../flat-remix-gnome_3.30.13-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking flat-remix-gnome (3.30.13-1) ...
Setting up flat-remix-gnome (3.30.13-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css to provide /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css (gdm3.css) in auto mode
$
```

to go back to default.. run the below command and choose the proper value which matches to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
```

Example:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
[sudo] password for maduri: 
There are 7 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                                                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css              20        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css                     15        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css                          10        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css         17        manual mode
  4            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Darkest/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css      17        manual mode
  5            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css   17        manual mode
  6            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css        17        manual mode
  7            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css              20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css to provide /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css (gdm3.css) in manual mode
$
```

About automatic mode and manual mode:

```
   automatic mode
          When  a  link  group is in automatic mode, the alternatives system ensures that the
          links in the group point to the highest priority alternative  appropriate  for  the
          group.

   manual mode
          When  a  link  group  is  in manual mode, the alternatives system will not make any
          changes to the system administrator's settings.
```

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html

Comment: Thank you for your clear and detailed answer. It worked well!

Comment: 1 thing i wanna know what is the status showing for the selection 0: auto mode and others are manual mode what is this for? One more thing the default login screen(the one replacing image 3) is back but the problem in it taping-to-click on touchpad is still there! How to fix this?

Comment: I tested the fixes in the links you shared, they dont work for me i get this `sudo -i
[sudo] password for amin:
root@ubuntu:~# xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
root@ubuntu:~# su gdm -s /bin/bash
gdm@ubuntu:/root$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true

(process:2210): dconf-WARNING **: 19:11:12.399: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=2d703d223bfa4c01bb2b500ad5cbf274 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1`

Comment: i managed to fix it using the link u gave me... but what i had noticed that i was logged in a Ubuntu Wayland Session and the `xhost +si:localuser:gdm` command wasnt working in wayland, i tried giving the commands in ubuntu with x11 and everything worked fine.