# changing the login screen background crashes login screen after rebooting

Tags: boot, gnome, login, desktop-background

sorry i'm new here. here's (quite, sorry about that) a bit of background info for this post: basically I used to run zorin 12 core but it effed up somehow after I did a sudo apt-get update/upgrade and shut down the machine. I booted it up the next day, it didn't show the zorin dot grid background or user logos, it froze on first login attempt at the login screen, then I clicked cancel, then after the 2nd login attempt it temporarily flashed a bunch of code before it went to a black screen with a white file icon labelled documents. and then it boot looped back to the same login screen again

and because I couldn't fix that, I just gave up, nuked the zorin partition (I already have a backup of the documents that were stored on the zorin partition in a Win10 folder) and installed ubuntu 18.04 via a USB stick I randomly found that happened to have the ISO on it. Win10 was already on there as it was a dual boot for my (sort of, me mates helped me build it) self-built machine.

---

Anyway, after the minimal install and using it a few times, I got fed up of the purple screen at login and made my own wallpaper in GIMP to replace it with.

I followed the advice in this thread ([Cannot change login screen background in 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086962/cannot-change-login-screen-background-in-18-10)) to attempt to change my login background screen and basically this happened -  when I rebooted the system to see if the new wallpaper had been set, I got a grey screen, my cursor kept moving frantically all over the place (but in a weird kind of slo-mo where you could see loads of other cursors behind it) and I had to move it quickly to the password box to be able to login.

what perplexes me is that I've triple checked the code in the gdm3.css/ubuntu.css and it doesn't make sense as I've followed the advice (from the top answer) to the letter. is this a bug? have I stupidly done something wrong without realising? i'll add a screenshot of the code in question, for reference (i've highlighted it to point out what i've edited)

[image: the screenshot can be found here]

EDIT: the cursor problem has now disappeared, however, the screen is still grey and my custom background image still isn't showing.

ANOTHER EDIT: tried rebooting AGAIN, login screen is still grey, when I lock the screen and login again, the screensaver is the warty final ubuntu one and the login screen is still grey.

YET ANOTHER EDIT: as @PRATAP suggested, I tried changing the background colour to green and it just went back to the original problem.

AND ANOTHER THING (yes, mr steptoe?)... @PRATAP the terminal can't locate package flat-remix-gnome and when I do that other command it says there's only one other alternative which is the ubuntu.css

Comment: edit your code.. you missed `;` `background-size: cover;`

Comment: just updated the code the cursor problem's gone but my screen's still grey. any ideas?

Comment: Hi.. `your screen is gray` you mean login screen? what is the output of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` and your OS is Ubuntu 18.04 rite?

Comment: could it be permissions issue on the jpg? maybe `sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/backgrounds/wildfire.jpg` or similar???

Comment: Ok.. what is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

Comment: yes the login screen is grey in colour. and yes the OS is ubuntu 18.04. and the output of ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css is lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 may 19 04:44  /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css -> /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css

Comment: PRATP - output of your command = There is only one alternative in link group gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css): /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
Nothing to configure.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I'd need to double check that but I remember opening it up in an admin window of nautilus, opening up the recipient folder as admin and moving one across to the other. I'll try the sudo chmod and see what happens

Comment: Ok.. when you log out and login.. check that background and once you are in desktop session.. lock the system and when you have to enter the password check that background.. and let us know both the backgrounds are same?

Comment: @PRATAP I'll have to reboot the system and update you on that one.

Comment: yes... reboot may solve this..

Comment: @scousepunx just to confirm your style sheet is working.. change your code first line like this and reboot.. `background-color: green;`

Comment: original problem means still the login background is gray?

Comment: grey AND cursor going funny. that was the original problem.

Comment: things seems normal with the results you posted for `ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` and `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`. Have you remembered you did any other changes to any other files? I recommend you to install update-alternatives for gdm3.css and try

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1121120/739431 study this post and install flat-remix-gnome for time being.. `sudo apt install flat-remix-gnome`

Comment: sorry, need to add the PPA from this link https://launchpad.net/~daniruiz/+archive/ubuntu/flat-remix

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniruiz/flat-remix` `sudo apt update && sudo apt install flat-remix-gnome`