# Mysterious image on first boot lock screen

Tags: 20.04, themes, gdm

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and noticed a weird behavior. When I select a wallpaper image, it is selected for both lock screen and background wallpaper, but on *every* first boot I see a mysterious image. I don't know where this is displayed from. Is a beach or something. I already checked my images on `/home` and even removed the wallpaper images from `/usr`, but the mysterious image is still there. How can I change it?

Comment: have you installed anything related to question.. what is the output of the command `update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource`

Comment: Please, please take a photo of this mysterious beach, add it to the question and satisfy our curiosity!

Comment: @PRATAP, yes, I installed and seems Flat remix is active, as the result:

------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Blue/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   100       modo automático
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource                          10        modo manual
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource               15        modo manual
  3            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Blue/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   100       modo manual

Answer (score 2):

your situation is similar to this post [Two different login screens on Ubuntu 18.10!](https://askubuntu.com/q/1120995/739431)

but instead of plain css file, it is using gresource file..

If you want to change the background keeping the Flat-Remix-Blue theme as it is, you need to manually extract the Flat-Remix-Blue's gresource file, edit the background as you wish and compile it back..

you can go through this post to understand the manual way [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227070/739431)

---

I have gone through the source code of flat-remix https://drasite.com/flat-remix-gnome

The better way is to reinstall the package again after replacing the background image from source and making the blur value to suitable value..

> git clone https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome
> cd flat-remix-gnome make && sudo make install

[image]

```
PKGNAME = flat-remix-gnome
MAINTAINER = Daniel Ruiz de Alegría <daniel@drasite.com>
PREFIX ?= /usr
THEMES ?= $(patsubst %/index.theme,%,$(wildcard */index.theme))
BASE_THEME ?= Flat-Remix-Blue
BLUR ?= 6
IS_UBUNTU ?= $(shell echo "$$(lsb_release -si 2> /dev/null)" | grep -q 'Ubuntu\|Pop' && echo true)
```

[image]

Comment: JESUSMARYJOSEPH that was it! I reverted it back to Yaru and now that beach image is gone! Thank you so much!